# Perfectly good queries on my sql taking more than 5 seconds

Tags: mysql, performance

Lately we are seeing some queries in mysql(master) logs but no idea why they are shown there:
Queries are `select/update table where id = <some integer>`.

---

1. There is index on id
2. table size is below 100 000
3. Rows scanned are in hundreds (sometimes < 100)
4. Server is running on extremely good hardware
5. there are no joins involved
6. We do not see any heavy activity running on database at that time
7. tables are innodb
8. the same queries generally don’t even take 50ms, but sometimes all the execution of these queries take about 4-8 seconds

One observation was all the similar "non-slow-but-weirdly-taking-high-time" queries take almost the same amount of time for some duration . I.e. queries like stated in the top will all take about 4.35 seconds with variation of 0.05 seconds.

Does the network latency/packets-drop affect mysql query timing?

Comment: How do you make the mysql connection in your productive code? Native driver or some kind of odbc? Have you tried to execute the query directly on the database or just with your application?

Comment: what is the exact datatype of your id column?

Comment: FYI a [lakh](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lakh) is `100K`

Answer (score 1):

```
show processlist;
show global status like '%onnect%';
show global status like '%open%';
```

Is anything backed up? Is it waiting in a queue? waiting for file handles? What are your max_connections, open-files-limit, thread_concurrency ?

One side question: does the network latency/packets-drop affect mysql query timing?
Yes, the timeout must occur before the query is resent by the client

Answer (score 0):

- Do you see these problems locally or over the network? If the latter, then obviously packet drops can affect your performance if you are measuring from the client.
- Is it running in a virtual machine that can affect the performance?
- Disk problems?
- How is serialization set up? Can it be a contention problem by many processes accessing the same row?
- You may want to enable the query/slow query logs to see if there is any sort of pattern that causes this.

Answer (score 0):

Mysql slow log is not representative source to learn about your slow queries. If something makes server work slow all queries usually go to slow log.

E.g. if you have some slow blocking select on MyISAM a lot of PK updates will go to slow log.

You need to search for other slow queries or server problems. What about load average on this particular machine? Isn't mysql displaced into swap memory? Other applications? Queries per second?